# Why retrieving soundcloud tracks gives 403 forbidden error?

Tags: soundcloud

I am trying to retrieve my uploaded tracks from soundcloud using this API
`https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID` after getting client_id from browser inspector, but it gives me **"403 Forbidden"**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language you are using, but I stumbled across the same problem in my c# application. I solved it by adding a new Header key-value pair to my GET request.

"Authorization":"OAuth x-xxxxx"

You get the OAuth token by logging in on your soundcloud and searching the Cookies for oauth_token. Just append that to "OAuth " and your are good to go. This also allows you to access some user-related features on the api.

Comment: Nice try but that does not work on my side, still 403 error with fetch function in JS.